# Creating a change log for a spreadsheet in microsoft teams

Tags: excel, flow, microsoft-teams

There's a spreadsheet inside of microsoft teams. I'd like to create an audit//change log for it, so whenever something changes, I can find out who did it, and what it was before and after.

Not quite doable with iterative calculations - the "who did it" is tricky.

Can't use VBA - it's inside of microsoft teams.

I heard about "Flows", and I'm trying to see if they'll work, but I'm not sure I properly understand what's going on. It doesn't look like there's a way to make a flow out of an Excel file being updated.

So my current question is: Is there a way to make a flow trigger off of an Excel file being changed in Sharepoint, and is there a way to trigger an Excel macro off of that?

Comment: I've not used Teams or SPO, but is enabling version history via Document Library setting an option?

Comment: I brought that up to management - no no, they want emails sent to people every time someone changes their thing. I'm going nuts.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, do you have the option of setting an Alert on the spreadsheet?  In SP 2013 it allows users to be notified when the document is edited, again, not sure if Teams will have alerts or not.

If you do have the option, set an alert on a test document - make it alert you when something changes in the file.  Then wait for the email alert to come through - they're a bit basic looking, but good for your purposes.  Actually [here's a guide](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/create-an-alert-to-get-notified-when-a-file-or-folder-changes-in-sharepoint-e5a79e7b-a146-46da-a9ef-d65409ba8918).

The only problem is, the email alert is triggered by even the slightest modification.  It might make management start sweating when they receive an email alert because someone has corrected a minor typo!  Without [version history](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/how-does-versioning-work-in-a-sharepoint-list-or-library-0f6cd105-974f-44a4-aadb-43ac5bdfd247), they wouldn't be able to see what was changed either!  Version history would allow you to compare the new version compared to older versions.

Comment: I looked into alerts, and while good, they only give half of what's being looked for - not only do we want to know who changed it, but WHAT they changed

Answer (score 0):

Yes, creating a [Flow in Power Automate](https://flow.microsoft.com) is the way to go:

- First create a **List** to hold the audit information you want to keep.
- Then create a new Flow in the Power Automate designer, choosing the **SharePoint "When an item is created or modified" Trigger** to start your Flow when a item in the Library behind your Teams Channel changes.
- Since you are only worried about the one file, your **next step should be a Condition Control** that checks if the triggering item is the File you are interested in.
- If that evaluates to `True`, then you can use the **SharePoint Create Item** action to save the who-what-when information from the Trigger as a new item in your custom audit List.
- If necessary, you can finish with the `Send an Email` action to create a fully customizable email with parameters from the Triggered item.